# Swagger error :Response validation failed: void does not allow a value

Tags: javascript, swagger

I'm just following egghead Build Node.js APIs with OpenAPI Spec (Swagger) tutorial. I wrote a function to save data as in tutorial 
but when I'm trying to save data, I've got

Build Node.js APIs with OpenAPI Spec (Swagger)

```
{
  "message": "Response validation failed: void does not allow a  value",
  "code": "INVALID_TYPE",
  "failedValidation": true,
  "path": [
  "paths",
  "/",
  "post",
  "responses",
  "200"
  ],
 "originalResponse": "{}"
}
```

I'm new to this ,so please can anyone help me with this